# IE: How to get :active to also work on parent element (CSS-only)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

In Chrome/Safari/Firefox, if the user clicks on a `span` inside an `a` tag, the `:active` psuedo-class appears to also be applied to the containing element / parent. However, in IE, this does not seem to be the case, and `:active` only is applied to the element being directly clicked on.

This is posing some challenges as I try to do `:active` styling on buttons whose markup is fairly complex.

[A simple example of this is here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skotzko/ZZMZn/). Click directly on the text in a non-IE browser, and then compare the :active state to what you get by clicking directly on the text in IE.

Is there a way to get the `:active` state to pass through to the containing `a` in IE? Assume no JS in the solution as a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do this in IE is to use the button element, rather than a link element, since without Javascript you cannot traverse the dom up to the parent.

The caveat though is that you don't get the yellow :active background from the span element anymore. Hope this helps.